# Smooth transition when changing navigation bar "prefersLargeTitles"

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, preferslargetitles

I have a view controller that is `pushed` onto a navigation stack. The stack has `navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`, whilst this new view controller has `navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false`. I achieve this using the following code in the view controller that is pushed onto the stack:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}
```

However, when I return back to the presenting view controller, the change in the navigation bar from `navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false` to `navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true` is a bit glitchy. Is there any way to make this smoother?

Many thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of directly changing the preference via the navigation controller, you should change the behavior via the navigation item of the specific view controller you would like to affect.

```
// Root UIViewController
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    }
}

// Pushed UIViewController
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
    }
}
```

You can remove the lines you have in `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear`.

Comment: Nice thanks, this works. As `ViewControllerA` pushes `ViewControllerB`, the navigation bar shrinks in size and moves up vertically; it reveals the black "base" screen. Is it possible to change this black colour? Thanks

Comment: @Callam In ViewControllerA I think you want `navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true` instead of  `navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always`     According to the documentation for largeTitleDisplayMode:  _"If the prefersLargeTitles property of the navigation bar is false, this property has no effect and the navigation item's title is always displayed as a small title."_   When setting `prefersLargeTitles = true`  it isn't necessary to also set `largeTitleDisplayMode = .always` in this case - just tried this now.